# MySQL CAST 3 integers as DATE. Error or do not recognize date

Tags: mysql

This is part of MySQL table

```
 Amount | DebitAccount | RecordYear | RecordMonth | RecordDay
```

In MySQL query need `RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay` change to `DATE`.

Based on many advices get such working code (I show the code **only as example** to see how it works)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * 

, CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate 


FROM 2_1_journal) DATA 
WHERE RecordDate <> ? AND DocumentDate = ?
ORDER BY RecordDate DESC
```

This code selects all from table, changes/converts separated integers as `RecordDate` and gives me data based on `WHERE`.

Here is second working code **also only as example**

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 
FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a 
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT DebitAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount FROM 2_1_journal WHERE 

CAST(RecordDay AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordMonth AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordYear AS UNSIGNED) != ? 

GROUP BY DebitAccount 
) d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)
```

Need this `CAST(RecordDay AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordMonth AS UNSIGNED) != ? AND CAST(RecordYear AS UNSIGNED) != ?` part of the second code

to change to this `, CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate` part of the first code.

I created such code

```
SELECT a.AccountNumber, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount 
FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DebitAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount , 

CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate 

FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE RecordDate = ? 
GROUP BY DebitAccount 
) d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount) 


/*below code is for purpose to show whole code*/
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CreditAccount, SUM( Amount ) AS Amount , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate FROM 2_1_journal WHERE RecordDate = ? GROUP BY CreditAccount ) c ON (a.AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount)
```

In output get this error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'RecordDate' in 'where clause'`

As understand `CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate` must be located in other place. But what place? Possibly need to add `DATA` as in the first example.

Code may look not understandable, but such is a code to get what is necessary. 
Please advice.

**Update**

Based on advice changed code

```
SELECT
a.AccountNumber, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount

FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DebitAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount , 

CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate,
CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate 

FROM 2_1_journal) DATA

WHERE RecordDate = 2013-01-20

GROUP BY DebitAccount 

) d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)
```

I know that in table is row with date 2013-01-20. But in output result is 0 and no error.

Possibly my negligence mistake in code....

Made conclusion that code checks date only in the first row of MySQL table. If in the first row date match to user's input, code sums all values in column `Amount`. If does not match, result is 0.

**Update 1**

Seems finally this is working code. At the moment output is as expected. If possible, please, suggest improvements

```
SELECT
a.AccountNumber, 
IFNULL( d.Amount, 0 ) - IFNULL( c.Amount, 0 ) AS Amount

FROM 18_7_ChartOfAccounts AS a

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DebitAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount FROM
( SELECT *  , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate FROM 2_1_journal) DATA
WHERE

RecordDate = ?

GROUP BY DebitAccount 

) d ON (a.AccountNumber = d.DebitAccount)

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CreditAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount FROM
( SELECT * , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate FROM 2_1_journal) DATA
WHERE

RecordDate = ?

GROUP BY CreditAccount 

) c ON (a.AccountNumber = c.CreditAccount)
```

Comment: How about using RecordYear, RecordMonth and RecordDay in WHERE instead of RecordDate or alternatively using DATE field in database as pointed out by @joachim Isaksson

Comment: Then again, the smallest change could be to use HAVING instead of WHERE

Comment: Until now did not know about `HAVING`... will check

Answer (score 3):

You can't just use the `CAST`, you're also missing the `SELECT` nesting from your first example. Without it, you can't use a calculated field in your `WHERE`;

```
SELECT DebitAccount, 
SUM( Amount ) AS Amount , 
CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate , 
CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate 
FROM 2_1_journal 
WHERE RecordDate = ? 
GROUP BY DebitAccount
```

...needs to be...

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT DebitAccount, 
  SUM( Amount ) AS Amount , 
  CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate,
  CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', DocumentYear,DocumentMonth,DocumentDay) AS DATE) DocumentDate 
  FROM 2_1_journal) DATA
WHERE RecordDate = ?
GROUP BY DebitAccount
```

That said, performance of this query will not be easy to maintain, you're doing `WHERE` on a calculated field, which will by necessity need to calculate the value for *all rows in the table* every time you execute the query. Having an actual `DATE` field in the table would speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: ... changed code. No error, but no results. I removed `WHERE RecordDate = ?` to check and without `WHERE` shows sum of all rows.

Comment: @user2360831 What are you passing in as `RecordDate`? A string or an actual date?

Comment: If i correctly understand, `RecordDate` includes values from `RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay`. The values in MySQL are definied as `char(4),char(2)char(2)`. Then with `CAST(CONCAT_WS('-', RecordYear,RecordMonth,RecordDay) AS DATE) RecordDate,` `RecordDate` becomes in form of 2013-01-20 and this must be actual date. Or may be i do not understand situation....

Comment: @user2360831 If you're comparing the date in `RecordDate` with a string passed in as a parameter, you may not match, since the date format is locale dependent. What you'll want to do is pass in a date object as a parameter to get a match.

Comment: Actually array to compare and to execute (user's input) looks like `Array ( [0] => 2014-05-03 [1] => 2014-05-03 )`. The same format is for `RocordDate` year-month-day. It appears that code checks date only in the first row of MySQL table. If in the first row date match to user's input, code sums all values in column `Amount`. If does not match, result is 0.